# Hair Particle System Collection: why does Hair Length Affect?

Tags: particles

I am using a hair particle system to populate a terrain with trees and rocks in blender 2.81. I created the instance tree using the sapling tree generator so there is one object for the leaves and one for the trunk/branches. I created the rock instance by tweaking an icosphere. To populate the terrain with them is used particles systems.  I used hair rather than standard particles as the trees and rocks are to stay static. For the trees I used the type as collection (as I had a collection with both the leaves and trunk/branches). For the rocks, the type I used was object. I noticed the hair length setting affects the size of the particles. As both object and collection types have a scale and scale randomness input it seems to me, when using these types, the hair length should have no effect. What do I set the hair length to so only the scale input value affects the scale?

Comment: really you can set it to anything static. Scale and Scale Randomness will then be the only setting to affect the final size.

Comment: HenrikD I think you are mistaken. I just tested if the hair length changes the particle size in b2.81 and it does. Maybe it was different in another version?